# Alphanumeric hashCode method

Tags: java, hash

I have a question that I can't figure out, and I don't know what's wrong. So I have a generator that generates a random alphanumeric string, of either two or three characters in length. To test that this `hashCode` method is "perfect", i stored both, the strings and their `hashCode`s in two `TreeMap`s: One that stores the `<String, Integer>` and another `<Integer, String>` in order to filter out duplicates.

Hypothetically, if my method was a perfect one, both of the `TreeMap`s would be the same length... But they're not.

I am trying to generate the `hashCode`s by taking each character, computing their integer value, then adding that integer value to a String, then turning that String into an Integer. Hypothetically, there shouldn't be any collisions, since each String has its own sequence of numbers. Why isn't this working?

For example, I have the strings "r0x" and "x0r".
Their `hashCode`s should be:

```
"114" + "0" + "120" --> "1140120" --> 1140120 and 

"120" + "0" + "114" --> "1200114" --> 1200114
```

I can't think of any instances in which two or more strings would have the same code in this way, yet, my test indicates that there is.

So my question is, should this thing be working? Is my test flawed? Or is my logic flawed?

Thanks!

Comment: "To test that this hashCode method is perfect" - what hashCode method? You've only told us of a method that generates a random string... and `hashCode` in Java returns `int`, not `String`. It would be a lot easier to help you if you'd post your code, expected results, and actual results. (It sounds like your basic idea is flawed, as strings with parts of "20 54" and "205" "4" would be equivalent... you probably want a separator in there.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you have

```
"114" + "0" + "120" --> "1140120" --> 1140120
```

But what about

```
"11" + "40" + "120" --> "1140120" --> 1140120
```

and

```
"11" + "401" + "20" --> "1140120" --> 1140120
```

You should be able to modify your program and see if the hashCode is already stored as a key in the map, and then find the corresponding value to find the collisions.

You can get unique results easily by simply considering that your strings are number in base 62 (0-9, a-z, A-Z, so 62 different characters). The hashCode for 123 would be computed this way:

```
1 * 62^2 + 2 * 62 + 3
```

The hashCode for ab (where a would have value 10 and b value 11) would be computed this way:

```
0 * 62^2 + 10 * 62 + 11
```

Comment: I disagree with your remark about using `String.hashCode()`. Although it's a good solution for unconstrained strings, the number of collisions for short, constrained strings is very high. In this particular case, there is a collision for about half the strings, e.g. `zz7` and `zxu`, `x4n` and `vrn`, etc.

Comment: Agreed. Removed that part.